# ssh command for searching inside files

Tags: search, ssh, grep

Some weeks ago 2 of my sites have been exploited probably from an ftp bruteforce attack corrupting lots of my websites files.
I found out that they usually insert the following code in js or php files:

```
[Trojan code removed as irrelevant to this question.]
```

I want to login via ssh and run a grep command searching all files and giving output only for the ones that have this code included.

Any help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I use this command to find all files that contain a specified string:

```
find /path/ -name "*.ext" -exec grep -l "sting" {} \;
```

Answer (score 5):

After you log in, just run:

```
find /path/to/fies -type f -name "*.js" -exec grep -il 'string' {}\; > output.txt
```

replacing "/path/to/files" and 'string' as appropriate, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Use `find` to [narrow by extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50676314/441878) and `grep` to [look inside each file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30138655/441878). Adding `-r` and `-I` to your grep will search recursively and ignore binary (e.g. git) files.

```
find ./ -name "*.php" -exec grep -r -l -I "Layer" {} \;
```